# How can I access the child's makeIterator function?

Tags: ios, swift, iterator, sequence

I have a parent class `BaseModels` which implement the protocol `Sequence`:

```
class BaseModel { 
    var dict : Dictionary
    init (json: AnyObject?) { dict = json as? Dictionary }
}
class BaseModels : Sequence {
    var arr : Array<Dictionary>

    init (json: AnyObject?) { arr = json as? Array<Dictionary> }
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<BaseModel> {
        var nextIndex = 0;

        return AnyIterator {
            guard let arr = self.arr, nextIndex < arr.count else { return nil }
            let curIndex = nextIndex; nextIndex += 1;
            return BaseModel(json: arr[curIndex] as AnyObject?)
        }
    }
}
```

And I have child class who inherited from this parent:

```
class Child : BaseModel { ... }
class Childs : BaseModels {
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Child> {
        var nextIndex = 0;

        return AnyIterator {
            guard let arr = self.arr, nextIndex < arr.count else { return nil }
            let curIndex = nextIndex; nextIndex += 1;
            return Child(json: arr[curIndex] as AnyObject?)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I do this:

```
let childs = Childs(json: someJsonArray);
for (idx, el) in childs.enumerate() {
    // when I check the el's data type in here, its type is actually BaseModel, not Child. 
}
```

Why the `el` type is BaseModel, not Child? How can I implement this correctly so that when I call `enumerate` or `for ... in ...`, it returns Child type class not BaseModel class?

PS: when I add `override` in front of `func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Child>`, Xcode says "Method does not override any method from its superclass".

Comment: what if you were to do `if let child = el as? Childs { print(child) }` in the for loop.

Comment: @jasonnoahchoi it prints `nil` value ...

Comment: @jasonnoahchoi but it's not printing nil value if I just print the child variable directly...

Comment: oh wait maybe it's `if let child = el as? Child { print(child) }` since you're enumerating Childs

Comment: @jasonnoahchoi yes, I was already trying change it into `Child` too, and the result is still `nil`... looks like it's actually really `BaseModel`, not child object inserted into parent's class (polymorph).